# universal app with completely different layout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

I have an iPhone project which completed successfully and pushed into AppStore. Now i want to change that project in to Universal project. But the problem is that iPhone layout and iPad layout is completely different. In iPhone i have common design, but in iPad it comes as a SplitViewController. Actually the problem is in xcode 6, We are dealing with auto layout and size classes. We have only one storyBoard to deal with iPhone interface and iPad interface. I have no idea about how to implement this. Implementing SplitView and configuring it for iPad when iPhone has an other design.!

If anyone already worked on these kind of projects, please tell me your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have dealt with the same kind of project , where I have different designs for iPhone & iPad . Though by default there is a single storyboard to be commonly used for iPhone & iPad but I added an additional storyboard and design them separately for iPhone & iPad , and in `AppDelegate's` `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method I conditionally load the storyboard based upon the device (either iphone or ipad) .

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main~iPad" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
}
else{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
}
```

[image: See attached image]

App is live in AppStore at the moment with no issues. Hope this approach will help you

Comment: are you sure this can be done by xcode 6.? when  the size classes are available  .?

Comment: Yes , I am pretty sure about the version <Version 6.1 (6A1052c)>